# DRBD Dual-Primary Obstacles

Tags: xen, centos5, mount, drbd

I have DRBD installed and configured on two different servers, everything is working as expected but I am having a horrible I/O disk read/write speed and network latency like crazy, my shared partition is 35 GB and it takes me days to fully sync between the two servers and 15 minutes to copy a 100 MB directory also I configured automatic split-brain recovery and it works fine but when it do happen one of the disks (the faulty one) gets the secondary stamp so it's not auto-mounted unless it's promoted to primary manually, any idea how to overcome the slow speed and automate the nodes promotions to primary after recovering from split-brain and fully sync with the other node so I could automount them during boot or even after the boot, I don't want to babysit the servers waiting for every single reboot?

```
global { usage-count no; }
common { syncer { al-extents 3389; rate 150M; } }
resource web {
  protocol C;
  startup {
    wfc-timeout 30;
    outdated-wfc-timeout 20;
    degr-wfc-timeout 30;
    become-primary-on both;
  }
  net {
    sndbuf-size 0;
    max-buffers 8000;
    max-epoch-size 8000;
    unplug-watermark 16;
    # cram-hmac-alg sha1;
    # shared-secret PASSWORD;
    allow-two-primaries;
    after-sb-0pri discard-zero-changes;
    after-sb-1pri discard-secondary;
    after-sb-2pri disconnect;
    rr-conflict disconnect;
  }
  on first-node {
    device /dev/drbd0;
    disk /dev/xvdc0;
    address 192.168.1.11:7789;
    meta-disk internal;
  }
  on second-node {
    device /dev/drbd0;
    disk /dev/xvdc0;
    address 192.168.1.12:7789;
    meta-disk internal;
  }
  disk {
    no-disk-barrier;
    no-disk-flushes;
    on-io-error detach;
    fencing resource-and-stonith;
  }
  handlers {
    split-brain "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-split-brain.sh root";
  #  fence-peer "/usr/lib/drbd/crm-fence-peer.sh";
    out-of-sync "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-out-of-sync.sh root";
  #  after-resync-target "/usr/lib/drbd/crm-unfence-peer.sh";
  #  local-io-error "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-io-error.sh; /usr/lib/drbd/notify-emerg$
  #  pri-on-incon-degr "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-pri-on-incon-degr.sh; /usr/lib/drbd/$
  #  pri-lost-after-sb "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-pri-lost-after-sb.sh; /usr/lib/drbd/$
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this in virtual servers? (I read `/dev/xvdc0`.)

Comment: yes in xen virtual environment!

Comment: How can you not mention this in your question? What kind of performance do you expect with your setup?

Comment: didn't you see xen in the tags, what is xen?

Comment: Sorry I must have overlooked this. I doubt DRBD is the right tool for you. DRBD in Xen and on top of this you synchronize via an IPsec tunnel - this is asking for trouble IMHO.

Comment: LOL :D I highly agree now and based on personal experience but to complete my goal any idea about the mount issue?

Comment: On a XEN-PV-DomU there are no performance issues. We have dozens of them running in a production environment. XEN has almost no overhead.

Comment: Can you guide me then?

Comment: Please explain why you do need constant dual primary mode C.

Comment: because both of the servers are primaries and there's a roundrobbin DNS configured, so how can I manage visitors coming to secondary node with Active/Passive setup? remember /var/www and /var/spool/mail are mounted on DRBD partition and soft-linked to their original places on both servers!

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate some areas of where the error can be. First check are the network interfaces behaving normal, check for errors and correct speed.

```
ifconfig -a   # (some lines removed)
 eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:X
      inet addr:172.2.2.11  Bcast:172.2.2.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1345026 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1465184 errors:2 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:2
      collisions:35456 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:897944732 (897.9 MB)  TX bytes:185044496 (185.0 MB)
```

Check if there are not a lot of errors, I have 2 when transmitting on a total of 1465184, which I don't find alarming. 
My number of collisions is higher than I want it to be.

```
# mii-tool eth0
eth0: negotiated 100baseTx-HD, link ok
```

Only 100 Mb. For me network topology would improve if I would get a Gigabit switch. Also I have HD, which is half duplex, also bad. My network interface is capable of 1000baseT-FD, so the bottleneck is the switch.

For you, if you have a second network interface on the servers, you could connect them directly to each other. Also ethtool eth0 will give nicer output.

If there are no network problems, check for hardisk errors.

```
# smartctl -t short /dev/sda    # test the harddisk

# smartctl -H /dev/sda           
smartctl 6.2 2013-04-20 r3812 [x86_64-linux-3.11.0-15-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

# smartctl --all  /dev/sda   # for all information
```

After that, check logfiles for errors, High CPU load? Maybe the encryption takes a long time.

Comment: No network problems, no hard-disk problems, no high CPU usage and log files are really normal, I don't use encryption as you see per configurations because I already use IPSec dedicated tunnel for DRBD on the private level!

Comment: Then Oliver is asking the right question, the overhead of Xen. Only for testing you want to run DRBD in a virtual environment.

Comment: is there any other tweaks or modifications to speed it even a little bit up and how about the split-brain mount issue?

Comment: The overhead of Xen probably causes the slowness, one shared resource for 2 virtual servers. I didn't expect it to be this slow, so there still could be a error in the setup somewhere. If you design for performance then run DRBD directly on metal.

Comment: thanks jris for the clarification, I know that xen will cause slowness but not in this way, I was amazed of such poor performance any idea about the mount issue?

Comment: I can't help, I don't know enough about the technology DRBD. Also your giving information from your point of view. You are probably very clever, so you leave out a lot of details. To increase the chance of people helping you, paint your problem and give a clear description with details.

Answer (score 0):

You set NO buffer and are driving protocol C.

So you wait for every single IO to complete on the remote side before it can be written locally.

Set your buffer to 8 MB and use protocol A instead.

Comment: Thanks Nils for your suggestion but I am on a dual-primary setup, protocol A is not an option for me ://